# How to call a derived class function from a vector of base class pointers?

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class A {
 private:
  int v1;

 public:
  void setv1(int v1) { this->v1 = v1; }
  int getv1() { return v1; }
  virtual void print() { cout << v1 << endl; }
};

class B : public A {
 private:
  int v2;

 public:
  void setv2(int v2) { this->v2 = v2; }
  int getv2() { return v2; }
  void print() {
    A::print();
    cout << v2 << endl;
  }
};

int main() {
  vector<A *> vect;
  B *b = new B();

  vect.push_back(b);

  vect.at(0)->setv2(5);
}
```

I am currently learning inheritance. I would like to call the setv2 function as shown, but when I do, the object in the vector no longer recognizes it. Is there a way to allow me to have a vector of base class pointers and allow the derived classes within it to call their functions?

Comment: The `B` object with an `A` interface located at `vect.at(0)` does not have a `setv2(int)` member function.  You need to do `dynamic_cast<B&>(*vect.at(0)).setv2(5);` or add a `virtual void setv2(int) = 0;` in the `A` class.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but since the code pushed back a value in the next-to-last line of code, `vect[0]` is a valid element. There's no need for the extra overhead of `vect.at(0)` in the last line..